# Categories take long time to load in snap-store, how do i fix it

Tags: 22.04, snap-store

Categories are taking long time to load in snap-store or sometimes it shows it as blank.

[image]

I used `killall snap-store` in terminal, this seemed to fix problem temporarily but is there a permanent solution?

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yes, that continues to be an issue with the snap store.

Comment: if you could upvote the question it would be helpful since i know an answer to a question here but can't answer since this is a new account and i have no reputation points, if you upvote i would be able to help somebody

Comment: New users are able to answer with 0 reputation unless the question is locked for some reason.

Comment: I can't answer, it is asking for atleast 5 rep

Comment: You should post a question on [meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com). Some questions cannot be answered by new users.  See: https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19284

Comment: Please formulate your question more like a question, It now reads as an observation, not a question.

Comment: This is not a question

Comment: done, i have edited it as question